# Can you have numbers where $1^2 = -1$ and $(-1)^2 = 1$?

Tags: group-theory

So I was wondering if there was a name for this kind of rule where you have two units, in a cycle, such that $1^n =\left\{\begin{array}{rl} 1&n\text{ is odd}\\-1&n\text{ is even}\end{array}\right.$ and $(-1)^n =\left\{\begin{array}{rl} -1&n\text{ is odd}\\1&n\text{ is even}\end{array}\right.$?

I tried to solve $1\times-1 = x\implies 1\times1\times-1 = 1\times x \implies -1\times-1 = 1\times x\implies 1 = 1\times x\implies e = x$ so there is at least a third unit with two distinct factors.

Does this system have some interesting properties? Or is it inconsistent and will break down at some point?

(Also I'm not sure how to tag this correctly, as I'm not entirely sure this is even a group.)

Comment: The nonzero elements in $\mathbb{Z}^2_2$ might be the closest things to what you're describing.  Note, with your set-up, 1 is not the identity element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If there were two elements $1, -1$ in the group (distinct from the identity, and where $-1$ is the name of an element, not necessarily an inverse of 1) such that $1^2=-1$ and $(-1)^2=1$ then it follows that $1^3=1^2\cdot 1=(-1)\cdot 1$, which has to be the identity element by your argument, which contradicts your condition that $1^3=1$.